# How to ignore system default proxy while using webview2 in C#

Tags: c#, webview2

I have searched for docs explaining about proxy settings in webview2 but found nothing. I also tried to use the code below as a function that runs in webview2's `CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted(object sender, Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.CoreWebView2InitializationCompletedEventArgs e)` ,but it doesn't work. What I looking for is a solution to completely ignore any proxy software and connect directly. This has really puzzled me for a week XD.

```
async Task proxy()
{
    CoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions options = new CoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions();
    options.AdditionalBrowserArguments = "--proxy-server=\"direct://\"";
    CoreWebView2Environment env = await CoreWebView2Environment.CreateAsync(null, null, options);
    await web.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(env);
}
```

Comment: [This](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues/193#issuecomment-691327266) looks relevant. TL;DR you can't do this *after* initialization.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll try the method.

Comment: I found the solution
`Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("WEBVIEW2_ADDITIONAL_BROWSER_ARGUMENTS", "--proxy-server=\"direct://\"");`
in C#, use this in the program.cs